# Enabling JavaScript in Orfox

Tags: configuration, android

Some websites require JavaScript to be enabled. How can I enable it in Orfox? (The option was under Settings in Orweb.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Menu -> NoScript -> Tick the boxes for the sites.

*or*

Menu -> Tools -> Add-ons -> NoScript -> Enable/Disable/Configure

***Beware***: whitelists and user-specific configurations are probably fingerprintable and enabling javascript at all might expose functionality that isn't fully protected against yet. Orfox is still not fully implementing the Tor Browser design spec!